# UITextField changing into UITextInputTraits

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a UIViewController subclass that has a UITextField. It is loading from a xib. However, whenever I try to access the roomName instance variable after the view is initialized (e.g. in viewDidLoad), the debugger shows it as UITextInputTraits.

Here is my interface.

```
@interface AddRoomViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>{
  IBOutlet UITextField *roomName;
  id<AddRoomDelegate> *delegate;
}

- (IBAction)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField;

- (void) done;

@property (nonatomic, copy) UITextField *roomName;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id <AddRoomDelegate> *delegate;
@end
```

I am new to iOS development so I'm sure that I just missed a connection or something, but I am stumped.

Edit: I understand that it is a protocol, but when I try to get the text from the UIText Field I get the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITextInputTraits text]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x4d16170'
```

Comment: `UITextField` conforms to the `UITextInputTraits` protocol. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextInputTraits_Protocol/Reference/UITextInputTraits.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextInputTraits

Comment: Not sure if this part of the problem or not, but I don't think it's a good idea to copy the `UITextField` in your property definition. Is there a particular reason why you're doing this?

Comment: That was indeed the problem. I removed the property definition (no reason why I had it in there) and it works! Feel free to add that as an answer and I'll gladly accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the @property definition for my UITextField and that fixed the problem.

Comment: We can also use a "@property (nonatomic, weak) .." definition if the text field is in xib file.

Answer (score 0):

`UITextInputTraits` is a protocol, which `UITextField` conforms to.